# Warning BC42025 when trying to applying VisualStyler.ApplyExcludeTag() method to Tab Control

Tags: vb.net, visual-styles

I try to apply *SkinSoft.VisualStyler.ApplyExcludeTag(control As Control, childControls As Boolean)* method to Tab Control to disable Skin for this control as below code:

```
Private Sub MaintenanceProgramForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 
    vssfVisualStyler.ApplyExcludeTag(FormClientsAndSites.tabClientsAndSites, False)
    'Some Code
End Sub
```

I received this warning:

> **BC42025**: Access of shared member, constant member, enum member or nested type through an instance; qualifying expression will not be evaluated.

How can I disable this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning occurs just to inform you that the `ApplyExcludeTag()` method is shared and thus doesn't need an instance of its containing class in order to be called.

Just call it on the class directly:

```
VisualStyler.ApplyExcludeTag(FormClientsAndSites.tabClientsAndSites, False)
```

---

**EXPLANATION**

Since you seem to be unaware of how `Shared` members work, here's a brief explanation:

Marking something as `Shared` makes it so that you *don't* need a specific instance in order to access a method, field or property of that type.

For example, *instance methods* work like this:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Sub SayHello()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
    End Sub 
End Class
```

In order to call this you first need to initialize an instance of the `SomeClass` class:

```
Dim cls As New SomeClass
cls.SayHello() 'Opens a message box that says "Hello World!".
```

However, when marking a method as `Shared` you no longer need to create an instance before being able to call it:

```
Public Class SomeClass
    Public Shared Sub SayHello()
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World!")
    End Sub 
End Class
```

```
SomeClass.SayHello() 'Opens a message box that says "Hello World!".
```

Based on the warning you got, we know that `ApplyExcludeTag()` is marked as `Shared`.

Comment: Is there a way to disable this Warning?

Comment: Yes there is, but why would you need to? By calling the method on the class instead like I explained in my answer the warning will disappear. Or is there a specific reason you prefer to call it via your variable over calling it directly on the class?

Comment: Would you please show me how to call it on the class while I'm new in VB.net?

Comment: @Ferekikoo : I updated my answer to include a brief explanation about how shared methods work compared to regular instance methods. I hope it'll help you get a better understanding on what the differences are and why you needed to call `ApplyExcludeTag()` that way.

Comment: @Ferekikoo : If my answer solved your problem please don't forget to mark it as accepted (can be done by pressing the tick/check mark on its left). If you still feel you don't understand or if you have other questions regarding the matter I'd be happy to answer them.

Comment: That Now I know how it works :), I tried to vote but unfortunately my reputation is less that 15, Thanks Again

Comment: @Ferekikoo : Glad I could help!